# Angular 5 Material Spinner is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, spinner

Angular 5 Material Spinner is not working

app.module.ts

```
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ]})
```

component.ts

```
import { MatSpinner } from '@angular/material';
```

component.html

```
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
```

am I missing any configuration.?

In [Reference](https://material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples), it's generating an SVG file for Spinner but I don't see anything inside mat-spinner tag.

Comment: What error you get?

Comment: i don't see any error in console. it not appearing in the browser, I inspect but i don't see any changes there.

Comment: Maybe the color is transparet ?

Comment: `<mat-spinner _ngcontent-c13></mat-spinner>` this is what i can see in the console.. i tried color change still.

Comment: A demo would be helpful here

Comment: Same problem with me. With spinner and also with mat-icon... the rest like inputs are working fine

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I tried to fork the mat-spinner example given and that works perfectly. The only difference that I could see is the way you import the progress spinner module instead of importing it from a specific path do this:

```
  import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material';
```

You don`t need to import anything inside your component as mat-spinner extends matprogressSpinner.

Inside the relevant html just do what you were doing i.e.

```
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
```

You can have a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/angular/eymjpelkpro which might give you some more context.

Comment: Now Spinner is coming but the i dont see that in browser, how can i change the color properties of spinner

Comment: you just need to pass the color property inside mat-progress-spinner like    <mat-progress-spinner
        class="example-margin"
        [color]="color"
        [mode]="mode"
        [value]="value">
    </mat-progress-spinner>

Comment: check this: https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbrmanaovrd?file=app%2Fprogress-spinner-configurable-example.html. I would also suggest you to go through the documentation and the example once. I think that will solve all your problems. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 17):

[mode]="determinate" << This will only show the circle but will not spin!

To

[mode]="'determinate'" // <<<< single quote for constant value

~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~

Also as mentiond by deanwilliammills, 
mode = "determinate"

Answer (score 7):

The key here for me was to import `BrowserAnimationsModule`. I'm using angular 10

inside your *app.module.ts* file
`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

inside `imports` array put `BrowserAnimationsModule` .

Comment: I had the NoOptionAnimationModule that was negating the BrowserAnimationModule. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I had a special case where the `mat-spinner` was not showing, with absolutely no errors in console or compilation but still was visible in the DOM.

I forgot to add the component where `mat-spinner` had to be used into the `declarations`-Array of the module...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../../global/material/material.module';
import { YourComponent} from './your.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [YourComponent], // <--- here this
    imports: [
        MaterialModule
    ],
})
export class SomeModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of [mode]="determinate"

That worked for me.
Seems like a bug Angular 5 people need to fix

My Code:

**Old:**

```
<mat-progress-spinner
    class="progressSpinner"
    [color]="myCustomColor"
    [mode]="determinate"
    [value]="myCustomValue">
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

New:

```
<mat-progress-spinner
    class="progressSpinner"
    [color]="myCustomColor"
    [value]="myCustomValue">
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component class you have to declare when to show and when to hide the spinner using

spinner.show();

spinner.hide();

Answer (score 0):

Any kind of animations will be supported only if you import BrowserAnimationsModule in the app.module.ts.

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

Answer (score 0):

For me, the imports were correct, but I overlooked an error message in the console, regarding missing angular core theme.

Importing a theme in the main style.scss file solved that for me.
@import "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

Answer (score 0):

I got this error `main.ts:5 Error: <circle> attribute r: A negative value is not valid. ("-2.5")`  (using version 16 of material) and Google gave me this page as a first result.

If anyone else is getting this error, this is because I had `strokeWidth > diameter`. That is, stroke width can't be larger than diameter